# Ad Blocker for iOS to block YouTube ads on iPad

Tags: ios, youtube, ipad-app, ad-blocker

I find myself being almost unable to watch YouTube anymore on my iPad, due to its increasingly obtrusive, invasive ads. On my laptop I have solved this with an ad blocker.

Question: **Is there a YouTube ad blocker for iOS as well?**

Not sure how that would work, would it require using a separate app? Is there something I can plug in or add on to the existing official YouTube app? Or would I need to watch YouTube in my browser (mostly Chrome on iOS in my case) and install an extension in there?

Answer (score 0):

I did a search for general ad-blockers on iOS recently and Apple deliberately broke most of them on purpose for sham reasons (something about using an unsupported VPN, except that some of them don't use VPNs).

Safari supports ad-blocking though.
https://www.imore.com/how-block-ads-your-iphone-or-ipad

For iOS ad blocking (at home), the best solution is to use a piece of hardware that serves as a friendly man-in-the-middle between the Internet and your phone. Something I would envision in the future is a heavy phone case that serves as both a spare battery and a nuisance-blocking box (connect the phone to the case, the case connects to the Internet and automatically filters out unwanted sites and domains)

For home use, you could create a network-wide adblocker:
https://lifehacker.com/create-a-network-wide-ad-blocker-with-a-raspberry-pi-1727295925

...or you could go all the way and get a professional grade all-in-one filter:
https://www.barracuda.com/products/websecuritygateway

Comment: Are any of these open source?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to [Cercube](http://cercube.com) and then sideload the ipa using [impactor](http://www.cydiaimpactor.com/) to have an ad free experience with background playing. You have to sideload it once a week though.

Answer (score 0):

AdGuard pro could be good. I use it on android; works very well. That said, it's being discontinued soon because Apple doesn't like it, so I'd download sooner rather than later.

Comment: Why doesn't Apple like it? Is it open source?